# To restrict lsqcurvefit's output to positive values

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization

I think this depends much on the objective function. 
However, if there are any other ways to limit it - it would be great. 
At least, my teacher says there is some option. 
However, I cannot find it from the [manual](http://se.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) in searching *positive*.

**Is there any setting to limit the output of every parameter to be positive from lsqcurvefit?**

### If positive values only through objective function and no option in lsqcurvefit for positive values

lsqcurvefit:

```
lsqcurvefit('count', params, V_vec, I_vec, [], [], options);
```

where there are some negative values in V_vec and I_vec.
The parameter options

```
options = optimset('TolFun', 10^-6, 'MaxIter', 100);
```

Assume your dummy objective function is

```
function [ x ] = count_i( params, V )
a = size(V);
for i = 1:a(1)
    if i == 1
        x(i,1) = fsolve( @(I) diode1( I, params, V(i) ), 3.4 ); 
    else
        x(i,1) = fsolve( @(I) diode1( I, params, V(i) ), x(i-1) );
    end
end
end
```

I have noticed that the selection of x0 that is here 3.4 affects much to the results from *lsqcurvefit*.

**How can you restrict lsqcurvefit to positive values by other methods?**
By objective function or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter #5, the lower bound.  Right now you are passing `[]` which means "all variables are unbounded below".  Use a lower bound of zero (vectorized of course) to make them non-negative.